# XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema infers type="xsd:unsignedByte" for UInt32 Property (.Net)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I am creating an XSD document from a C# class.

This class has a property with type `UInt32` that I expect to map to `xs:unsignedInt` based on this article:

[Mapping XML Data Types to CLR Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/mapping-xml-data-types-to-clr-types)

The code for generating the .xsd is:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("class.xml");
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();

schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);
```

However, in the xsd I see the element to be inferred to:
`<xsd:element name="u32Value" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />`

Why is the type not what I expect?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemainference.inferenceoption?view=net-7.0

Comment: What is the code for 'class.xml'? Turning a C# object to XML, then inferring an XSD from that XML does not always preserve original type information from the C# class definition. `xs:unsignedByte` is from 0 to 255, so maybe the actual values of the `u32Value` element are always between that range. The schema inference class probably never saw a value beyond 255 so it inferred the `unsignedByte` type.

Comment: Thanks for the reference jdweng
However, 
I am using XmlSchemaInference. TypeInference == Restricted. Using Relaxed seems to be the opposite of what I want as explained here in the Remarks section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemainference.typeinference?view=net-7.0#system-xml-schema-xmlschemainference-typeinference

Comment: Thanks mamift.
You're correct. I originally planned on using xsd.exe to create the xsd file, but upon getting errors, decided to generate it programmatically through XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema. I neglected to consider the nuance you pointed out. When I initialize the property to UInt32.MaxValue, I get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I discovered that I needed to initialize the Property to a value to help the XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema infer the proper type.

I originally planned on using xsd.exe to create the xsd file, but upon getting errors, decided to generate it programmatically through XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema. I neglected to consider the nuance you pointed out. When I initialize the property to UInt32.MaxValue, I get the expected results.